# Script: Transpose, Find and Save

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some data containing, Dates, Usernames and an average percent that i want to save in a certain way. My problem is that the order of the usernames can change depending on if new ones are added. I therefore need to "find" a specific username and then save the percentage data in the correct column.

I have found some code that partially helps me save the data that i need. But i could use some help in the "find" the corresponding username and save it in a certain Column part.

```
function save() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Result');
 var range = ss.getRange('B1:B10');
 var data = range.getValues();


 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Archive');

   ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,data[0].length,data.length)
    .setValues(Object.keys(data[0]).map ( function (columnNumber) {
      return data.map( function (row) {
        return row[columnNumber];
      });
    }));
  }
```

Basically from this: [image: Data]

To a result that looks like this:
[image: Result]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Where did the dates come from?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry, if doable they would be added in the script. But right here its just a `today()` which got saved through another script

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet. Would you also ensure that the spreadsheet contains an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: @GanX If you are still looking for assistance with this problem, would you please respond here. And would you also _please_ share your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tedinoz Sorry for my slow reply, i have to get used to the notifications here. I made a sample sheet for you to look at, but its basically the same as in my screenshots. I set it so you also can edit it if you have suggestions. The data is just dummy data so feel free.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_CojinxhHnIFOkOAeX6sP8MHpZFROWIP80yWhNEMzeE/edit#gid=1289559644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright for anyone out there that may have a similar problem, this is what i ended up with.

```
function extractAttendance() {
    var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var attendanceTab = currentSheet.getSheetByName('Data_Filtered');
    var userData = attendanceTab.getRange('B1:B').getValues();

    var percentageData = attendanceTab.getRange('I1:I').getValues();

    var archiveTab = currentSheet.getSheetByName('Archive');
    var existingUsersRow = archiveTab.getRange('1:1');

    var newRowNumber = archiveTab.getLastRow() + 1;
    archiveTab.getRange(newRowNumber, 1).setValue(new Date());

    for (var i = 1; i < userData.length; i++) {
        var user = userData[i][0];
      if (user === '') {
        continue;
      }
        var existingUsers = existingUsersRow.getValues()[0];
        var exists = false;
        var existingColumnNumber = -1;

        for (var j = 0; j < existingUsers.length; j++) {
            if (existingUsers[j] === user) {
                exists = true;
                existingColumnNumber = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (exists) {
            archiveTab.getRange(newRowNumber, existingColumnNumber).setValue(percentageData[i]);
        } else {
            var newColumnNumber = archiveTab.getLastColumn() + 1;
            archiveTab.getRange(1, newColumnNumber).setValue(user);
            archiveTab.getRange(newRowNumber, newColumnNumber).setValue(percentageData[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to implement your desired functionality through looping rather than through mapping.

The following code retrieves all users ad their percentage data in ‘Result’ and transfers the data (in the format you desire) to "Archive" with the percentages data pasted with the corresponding timestamp into the first empty row.

```
function save() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Result');
 var range = ss.getRange('B1:B');
 var percentageRange = ss.getRange('G1:G');
 var userData = range.getValues();
 var percentageData = percentageRange.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Archive');

   var userRow=1;
   var percentageRow=(ts.getLastRow()+1)
  for(var i=0; i<=userData.length; i++)
   {
     {
       var j=(i+2);
       ts.getRange(userRow, j).setValue(userData[i])
       ts.getRange(percentageRow, 1).setValue(new Date())
       ts.getRange(percentageRow, j).setValue(percentageData[i])
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Whether you loop or map, how can this be an improvement if it requires that one must declare the username is a variable `var userName="Username3";`? It would be useful to see the output created by this code - would you include a screenshot?

Comment: Ahh yes, i see where you are going with this. But there are a few problems.

The usernames will not always be the same as new users may be added over time. Also as Tedinoz pointed out, it needs to run every name in the column and not just the one specified in "userName". I really do like your idea about mapping the percentages to the usernames though.

@Tedinoz https://imgur.com/AtXufCu

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. If you always want to update all users - this is even easier. I will edit my answer and paste the corresponding source code. The new code will retrieve all users from "Result"and paste the in the first empty row in "Archive" - with the corresponding timestamp.

Comment: This one has me confused to be honest. It doesn't bring over the names and it creates an unending amount of columns.

Check out the sheet below for reference, and thank you for your efforts!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_CojinxhHnIFOkOAeX6sP8MHpZFROWIP80yWhNEMzeE/edit#gid=0

Comment: For this implementation - just change:  var range = ss.getRange('B1:B');
 var percentageRange = ss.getRange('I1:I'); to  var range = ss.getRange('B2:B');
 var percentageRange = ss.getRange('I2:I');

Comment: That doesn't really fix the issue though. It still creates hundreds of columns when you run it and it also doesn't copy the names.

Comment: What the script is doing is to transform all your rows in Data_Dump into columns in Script_Test. For some reason you had many empty rows in Data_Dumb (I erased them now) - this is why you got so many empty columns.  getRange('B1:B') tells Appscript to consider as the range all cell in the B column starting with B2. If you know in advance how many entries you expect - you can  set a maximum limit for the range, for example getRange('B1:B20'). Another possibility would be to use ss.getDataRange() - this makes sheets select automatically all cells actually containing data as the range.

Comment: Please refer here for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()